# There's always an error message saying "The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'."

Tags: c#, odbc

```
 private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
     conn.ConnectionString =
              "Dsn=mdc;" +
              "Uid=root;" +
              "Pwd=;";
     OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select * from tbl_delivery");
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

     DataSet dt = new DataSet();
     OdbcDataAdapter ds = new OdbcDataAdapter();
     ds.Fill(dt);
     tbl_deliveryDataGridView.DataSource = dt; 
     try
     {
         conn.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

***there is always an error everytime i am going to run the program, i don't know where is the error. i tried editing the code yet still the error keeps on popping out.***

Answer (score 0):

You getting error because you haven't assign OdbcCommand to OdbcDataAdapter and trying to execute Fill method. you should assign OdbcCommand to OdbcDataAdapter like this

```
 OdbcDataAdapter ds = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd,conn);
```

And then try to Fill DataTable

```
    conn.Open();
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    OdbcDataAdapter ds = new OdbcDataAdapter();
    ds.Fill(dt);
    tbl_deliveryDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```